# ASP.NET Core schedule long running task and notify the user back when completed with SignalR

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, signalr

We have blazor app where users can see their recorded videos and export bookmarks (basically cut smaller portion of the video file). When bookmark is exported the video file is deleted. So we don't keep track of the file anywhere. Just send it back when ready.

The problem is that sometimes is really slow and the http request times out. There is 2 solutions for that, scheduling background work and keeping the state of the export in the database and our blazor app can poll every X secs to check if its over. But that means extra table in our DB, inserting/deleting records etc.

The other solution is scheduling the task and a `BackgroundService` to process it and when its over to notify the user back via `SignalR`, but if he hasn't left yet. If he left during exporting cancel the exporting/delete the file if its done.

The scheduling and processing is quite easy (e.g. https://blog.elmah.io/async-processing-of-long-running-tasks-in-asp-net-core/), but what I cannot think of, how can I push this task in the queue from `SignalR` hub and when the task is processed to notify **the user which initiated the task**. If I call `_backgroundWorkerQueue.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` inside the hub method this will not be awaited and my assumption is that the hub will be destroyed and the connection with the user will be lost, so I cannot just pass the connectionId/hubcontext in the callback func.

Comment: Are you using built in Identity?

Answer (score 0):

The request comes with a user Id. The user when they connect to the hub could join a group that is his userId or alias..  When the long running service is finished you push a message to the user by sending to the same group only they should be in. To initiate messages from the server **inject** `IHubContext<YourHubClassName>` into your long running service. The alternative to the group thing is on the server is to map each connectionId to a userId and then use the hubcontext to message that connectionId.

```cs
public class SomeLongRunningService 
{
    public SomeLongRunningService (IHubContext<YourHubClassName> hubcontext)
    {
        ....
```